# send image to another iphone using gamekit

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, gamekit

I googled around all the thing but unable to get the expected thing, As i want to send the image to another iphone or ipad using gamekit, Any sample code for my begining approch will be appreciated.

Thanks Neha

Comment: -1. SO is not a 'PLZ GIMME TEH CODEZ' site.

Comment: This is something that you should be searching for on Github,etc. not posting as a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can send image using to another iPhone by using `[[GCHelper sharedInstance].match sendDataToAllPlayers:data withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataUnreliable error:&error];` method.

For that you have to first convert your UIImage to NSData and then using `GKMatchSendDataUnreliable` this mode you can send image to another iPhone.

GKMatchSendDataUnreliable is used for sending large amount of data to another device.

```
BOOL success = [match sendDataToAllPlayers:data withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataUnreliable error:&error];

            if (!success) {
                CCLOG(@"Error sending init packet");

            }
```